# Check if arguments[files] exist or not in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, exit

This is part of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USAGE(){
    echo "Usage: ./`basename $0` <File1> <File2>"
}

if [ "$#" -ne "2" ]; then
    USAGE
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "The file \"$1\" does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
    echo "The file \"$2\" does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi
```

I want to check if **file1** does not exist prints:

```
The file "file1" does not exist!
```

if **file2** does not exist prints:

```
The file "file2" does not exist!
```

If both does not exist prints:

```
The files "file1" and "file2" don't exist!
```

How can I do that?

I want to know what the most logical (STANDARD) method is.

Comment: I saw your edit. Double quotes are not necessary with `[[ ]]` unless they're second argument to `==`. Word splitting and pathname expansion doesn't occur in `[[ ]]` that's why it's the recommended form in bash.

Comment: The *de facto* standard is to only report one error at a time; if the failure of `file1` to exist is enough to abort the program and `file1` doesn't exist, the existence of `file2` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course you can do that... . There are many ways to obtain this. The most simple maybe:

```
if [ ! -f "$1" ] && [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
    echo "The files \"$1\" and \"$2\" do not exist!"
    exit 1
else
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        echo "The file \"$1\" does not exist!"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
        echo "The file \"$2\" does not exist!"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

If you don't want to do the checks two time, you can work with variables; something like this:

```
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    NOT1=1
fi
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    NOT2=1
fi
if [ -n "$NOT1" ] && [ -n "$NOT2" ] 
....
```

Comment: Thank you...But there is also a problem..When I run script in this way:`bash script.sh sd ff` ||| The following error occurs. because we don't use `exit`: The files "sd" and "ff" do not exist!
cat: sd: No such file or directory

Comment: should do: `echo "The files \"$1\" and \"$2\" do not exist!" && exit 1`

Comment: @ Chris Maes. No problem :) ... when I don't use `exit 1` my script continue and respond errors.. because of file which I should work with...

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this so you only have to `test` each file once:

```
status=""
for file; do
    [ -f "$file" ]
    status+=$?
done

case $status in
    11)
        echo "The files \"$1\" and \"$2\" do not exist!"
        exit 1
        ;;
    10)
        echo "The file \"$1\" does not exist!"
        exit 1
        ;;
    01)
        echo "The file \"$2\" does not exist!"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Your function can be simplified: `not_file() { [ ! -f "$1" ]; }`

Comment: True, function doesn't really make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

The logical is

```
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    if [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
        echo "The files \"$file1\" and \"$file2\" don't exist!"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "The file \"$1\" does not exist!"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

if [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
    echo "The file \"$2\" does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi
```

The readable is

```
if [ ! -f "$1" -a ! -f "$2" ]; then
    echo "The files \"$file1\" and \"$file2\" don't exist!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "The file \"$1\" does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
    echo "The file \"$2\" does not exist!"
    exit 1
fi
```

The readable is preferred.

Also not testing for existence twice as Chris Maes said could be logical too.

Comment: `[ ! -f "$1" ] && [ ! -f "$2" ]` is [preferred by the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16) over the use of `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified for `Bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <File1> <File2>"
elif [[ ! -f $1 && ! -f $2 ]]; then
    echo "The files \"$1\" and \"$2\" don't exist!"
elif [[ ! -f $1 ]]; then
    echo "The file \"$1\" does not exist!"
elif [[ ! -f $2 ]]; then
    echo "The file \"$2\" does not exist!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this additional condition:

```
if [ ! -f "$1" ] && [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
  echo "Both files does not exist!"
  exit 1
fi
```

I'm not sure you need that though. The two conditions you have, for first and second file, will be informative enough.

Alternatively, you can use just one condition by using logical OR `||`. I'd suspect users wouldn't have an issue with understanding their misues of the script:

```
if [ ! -f "$1" ] || [ ! -f "$2" ]; then
  USAGE
  exit 1
fi
```